# Button setonclick listener is not working correctly

Tags: java, android-studio

when I press the save button does not work after pressing it several time button is working sometimes first-time press is working sometimes after pressing moreover 10 times button is not working.Also i have toast messege to determine it is working or not the toast messege appear after pressing several time to the button.

```
 binding.savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Settringsactivity.this,"ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String status=binding.etStatus.getText().toString();
                    String username=binding.etUsername.getText().toString();

                HashMap<String, Object> obj=new HashMap<>();
                Toast.makeText(Settringsactivity.this,username,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                obj.put("username",username);
                obj.put("about",status);
                if(name!=null) {
                    Toast.makeText(Settringsactivity.this,"Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    database.getReference().child("Users").child(name).updateChildren(obj);
                }
            }
        });


     Here is the xml code 
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/savebtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:foregroundTint="#B11B1B"
    tools:context=".Settringsactivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settingsbackarraow"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/flinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/settingsbackarraow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileimage"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_plus" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textColor="#100606" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:hint="Enter your name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textColor="#100606" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="About"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:elevation="15sp"
            android:background="#1966FB"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Save" />


    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a typo in your SettingsActivity and therefore the context is not correct? Settringsactivity

Comment: No all the things are correct if there was a typo then the button should not work at all .button onclick is working randomly.

Comment: Can you provide a more useful piece of code to detemine how to solve your problem? Everything seems fine from this stadpoint but the bug could be related to your binding and the boilerplate code...

Comment: Yes, the problem was solved I defined savein id in relative layout.I have solved that problem after reading your comment thank you for your time and help.